# To send file as attachment using HTTP request node in IIB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have requirement to send a file over API as attachment. This works fine from Postman. I have to implement same using IIB using HTTP Request Node. I am not able to find any property on the node related to attachment. Can anyone suggest the solution

[I want to implement this binary file upload option via HTTP request node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLYnI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is already a published API that you are sending that attachment to it and you want to develop some interface from IIB to mask this API , Correct ? If it is correct then all what you need is to set the HTTPRequest Node to work in the **gateway operation mode** then you will have to specify the URL of the published API and of course an HTTPInput node in the beginning of the flow.